# Convert to polar and evaluate

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

I have

$$z= x^2 + y^2$$
$$z=2x$$

I set them equal to get their intersection, 
I get

$$2x= x^2 + y^2$$

$$0= x^2 -2x +y^2$$

by completing square I get

$$y= \pm \sqrt{1-(x-1)^2}$$

I need to put this into polar coordinates and then evaluate the integral. I was trying to shift back to the origin.

Comment: Sorry, new to this, thanks for editing it.

Comment: superman you haven't clearly stated ur question .Are you to find volume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your circle is centered at $(1,0)$ and radius $1$ .Put $x=r\cos \theta$ and $y=r\sin \theta$ in your equation of circle .You will get $r$ bounds from there .Your $\theta$ bounds will be from $-\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ to $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ since your circle lies in $1$st and $4$th quadrant.No need to shift origin

[image]
[image]

For further help, you can refer [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGqzsq0erqU7h6_bpE-CgJp4iX5aRju28) playlist. Lecture `8` and `9` contains multiple integration

Comment: @Integrator Thanks for edit.looks better now

Comment: I am still not understanding because..  x=rcosθ y=rsinθ but my equation leaves a rsinθ on left side

Comment: @Superman i am editing my answer .wait

Comment: I SEE now...thank you soo much. so the integral will just be from 0 to 2pi | 0 to 2cosθ rdrdθ   correct??

Comment: I am finding area so it will simply be 0 to 2pi | 0 to 2cosθ rdrdθ correct?

Comment: @Superman Why o to $2\pi$.pls check figure in my solution .

Comment: did you get 4π?

Comment: @Superman i didn't calculated  and nor will i ,but i ensure u limits are correct